# How can I delay the loading of my controller?

Tags: angularjs

How can I delay the loading of my controller till the HTML page has been loaded in AngularJS?
I am using the angular spinner. My code is as below

```
<span spinner-key="spinner-mySpinner">
<div>...</div>
</span>
```

I am calling the spinner before calling a promise for loading data.

```
...
mySpinner.spin('spinner-mySpinner');
loadDataPromise = file.getFileDetails(vm.id, vm.path);
...
loadDataPromise.finally(function () {
            mySpinner.stop('spinner-mySpinner');
        }
...
```

I am not able to see the spinner.
I think that my controller is getting initialized before the HTML page gets loaded.
Is there a way in which I can delay my controller till the HTML page has loaded?

Comment: Can you provide a plunker?

Comment: Where does your spinner live? Is it on the view the controller is bound to or is it in the main view, eg index.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include your controller functionallity inside a function declared inside of your controller as $scope.func = ... And include a js script in your view that on window.load calls that function of your controller.

```
angular.module('MyModule', [])
    .controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myfunction = function () {
        //do your stuff
    };
});

window.onload = function () {
    angular.element(document.getElementById('YourElementId')).scope().myfunction();
}
```

If your are assigning a controller from the route provider you should set an id to your division where you have the ng-view for example id="ngview" and call your function the following way:

```
window.onload = function () {
        angular.element(document.getElementById('ngview')).scope().myfunction();
}
```

Hope it helps!